# How get order status in observer?

Tags: magento, events, orders, observers

Under the event `sales_order_save_after`, I have some code in observer to get the order status.

```
public function saveBookingInfoFromOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){                
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        //$last_orderid = $order->getIncrementId();

        $last_orderid = $order->getId();
        $order_status = $order->getStatus();
}
```

However, order status is not coming. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Event `sales_order_save_after` is a bit tricky. The first time it's triggered Order is not yet commited to DB, and more to that - it actually doesn't have State and Status set yet.

If you want to get Status, there are other events more suitable for you:

1. `sales_order_payment_place_end` - this is triggered in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment::place` method right after `$order->setState` is done.
   The `place` function itself is a afterCommit callback for order saving transaction process.
2. `sales_order_save_commit_after` - this is triggered when all afterCommits are processed
3. `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success` - this is the final event in `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote::submitOrder` method - at the moment it's dispatched the Order will surely have all the data, and you can be sure that there were no errors during order creation.

Comment: 1 - i can not use this one : sales_order_payment_place_end as this contain only payment info, i tried

Comment: 2- sales_model_service_quote_submit_success this event brings success for me, you are absolutely right my mentioned event was not getting the order status as it was not in the DB, at that time. So i changed to this event and it worked. thanks